# how to populate dropdown list using using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

My javascript:

```
    var countrygroup = [
    "AFG-Afghanistan",
    "ALA-Åland Islands",
    "ALB-Albania",
    "DZA-Algeria",
    "ASM-American Samoa",
    "AND-Andorra",
    "AGO-Angola",
    "AIA-Anguilla",
    "ATA-Antarctica",
    "ATG-Antigua and Barbuda",
    "ARG-Argentina",
    "ARM-Armenia",
    "ABW-Aruba",
    "AUS-Australia"
    ];

    $(function() {

    $.each( countrygroup, function( i, a ){
        var sep = a.split('-');
        $("#country").append('<option value="' + sep[0] + '">' + sep[1] +'</option>');
    });
    });
```

---

php:

```
    <form action="validation.php" method="post">
        <table width="250" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>UserId:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="userId" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country Code:</td>
            <td><span class="input">
                 <select name="country" id="country" style="width:100%; white-space:nowrap">
                      <option value="NIL">Country</option>
        <!-- Use jquery to populate options -->
                 </select>
                </span>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td>Password:</td>
              <td><input type="password" name="pwd" required></td>
       </tr>
      <tr align="left">
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
 <script src="js/dropdown_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I  want  to  populate  the country list into my dropdown list name country. However all it show was the word "country" in the dropdownlist. What's wrong with my codes? The other time i use the same codes seem to be working but not this. Did i miss out something?

Comment: I didn't see the jQuery library loaded anywhere.

Comment: Any error in the `console`?

Comment: what is there in dropdown_script.js file??

Comment: @AshrafPurno no error

Comment: @Amarnasan sorry it is javascript not jquery

Comment: @Niranjan it is listed in the first box

Comment: I think it is not working because you were actually using jQuery but you didn't know. And it has worked for you previously because you were loading the jQuery library but you didn't know. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the jQuery library. Preferably at the bottom (because of efficiency loading reasons), just before loading your javascript (which should NOT be in the head as someone suggested).

Answer (score 0):

It is working in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfzreetf/). You should put the script in the `head` section of the page:

```
<script src="js/dropdown_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, please note that there is recommended to use absolute paths in order to avoid getting 404 errors: `/js/dropdown_script.js` instead of `js/dropdown_script.js`

As Amarnasan has commented, please make sure you include the jQuery library right before the `dropdown_script.js`